# When installing just PHP on Windows, all php extensions are commented out by default?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-ini

I'm trying to get Laravel installed and when running composer I get lots of errors along the lines of `the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system` except there are dozens. It's really tiring going one by one and uncommenting these. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to just install apache(edit: I meant XAMPP) and its default `php.ini` will have better default options?

Is there a way to get a .ini file that has the most common stuff available? Can I just uncomment all extensions or is there a reason that's a bad idea?

Comment: Apache doesn't actually install a `php.ini` does it? One good idea is to copy your `.ini` or all config files in general and re-use them where you see fit and modify as needed. And yes, you have to uncomment PHP extensions you want. One other thing is to be sure the extension you're uncommenting exists in the same directory as the `php.ini` file else just add the directory path to the extension plus the extension name.

Comment: I meant to say, install something like WAMP/XAMPP/Laragon, which would include php.

Comment: It's been too long since I've used any of those. Just to add to the list there also exists EasyPHP. Those will definitely provide a `php.ini` and possibly with certain extensions already enabled. If not then there's always just uncommenting and modifying the ones you want. For example I've got the PHP LDAP extension commented out `;extension=ext/php_ldap.dll` but mbstring enabled
`extension=ext/php_mbstring.dll`

Comment: wamp,xampp comes with php.ini and wamp is easiest to enable extensions..

Comment: Unless you'd like to install all this on your Windows machine for practice, your best bet would be to take a look at Laravel's Homestead (VM box used with Vagrant) for your development.

Comment: @patricus I am using Homestead, but I don't want to have to run composer from within the VM all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I just uncomment all extensions or is there a reason that's a bad idea?

Yes, you can uncomment all extensions, but that won't improve your user experience :)

In general: **enable only PHP extensions, you really need**

The more dynamic extensions PHP needs to load, the more stuff it has to load and process during startup and the more time it takes. So, the startup will be slower.

For instance, enabling the default extension `php_pdo_firebird.dll` doesn't gain you anything, except, when you really want to access the Firebird database from PHP via PDO.

> Is there a way to get a .ini file that has the most common stuff available?

The PHP extensions shipped by PHP itself are all listed in `php.ini`.
There is also `php.ini-development` with some dev configurations.

If everything is off by default, then i suggest to enable curl + openssl, mysql, sqlite, mbstring for a start, because:

- Curl and Openssl are needed to get Composer running,
- Mysql and Sqlite to support these often used databases,
- mbstring for UTF8 stuff
- and whenever some library meows enable some more ,)

Comment: If this install of PHP is literally only for running composer, is it still a bad idea to uncomment them all?

Comment: Feel free to enable them all and try things, but the best practice is to enable only the ones you really need and leave the rest disabled.